# How to get the global offset of an autodesk viewable?

Tags: autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

Listing viewables with  `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/{urn}/metadata` and taking a 3D one, how do I get it's global offset without loading it in viewer?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the global offset is not available through any of the Model Derivative APIs. The information is "baked" into the proprietary SVF/SVF2 file format that's typically loaded into the Viewer. What you *could* do is use the [forge-convert-utils](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-convert-utils) library to parse the SVF, and extract the global offset there.